# Проблема с наложеием маски на лицо OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

При обнаружении лица приложение падает. И даже не выбивает ошибку, просто application terminated.
Вдохновением послужили эти материалы:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749867/mask-not-displayed-in-opencv-camera-preview
http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/11/putting-mask-on-face-using-opencv.html

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private JavaCameraView mJavaCameraView;
private Mat mRgba;
private Mat mask;
private CascadeClassifier cascadeClassifier;
private int mAbsoluteFaceSize = 0;

static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");

    if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV loaded!");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV NOT loaded!");
    }
}

BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS: {
                mJavaCameraView.enableView();
                InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.haarcascade_frontalface_alt2);
                File cascadeDir = getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                File mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");
                FileOutputStream os = null;
                try {
                    os = new FileOutputStream(mCascadeFile);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    is.close();
                    os.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            break;
            default: {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mJavaCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
    mJavaCameraView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mJavaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "5.jpg");

        mask = imread(file.getPath(), -1);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "File NOT find");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mJavaCameraView != null) {
        mJavaCameraView.disableView();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mJavaCameraView != null) {
        mJavaCameraView.disableView();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV loaded");
        mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV NOT loaded!!!");
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION, this, mLoaderCallback);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mRgba = new Mat(width, height, CvType.CV_8UC4);
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    mRgba.release();
}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();
    cascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(mRgba, faces, 1.1, 2, 1,//Objdetect.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE,
            new Size(mAbsoluteFaceSize, mAbsoluteFaceSize), new Size());
    Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++) {
        Point center = new Point(facesArray[i].x + facesArray[i].width / 2, facesArray[i].y + facesArray[i].height / 2);
        mRgba = putMask(mRgba, center, new Size(facesArray[i].width, facesArray[i].height));
    }


    return mRgba;
}

private Mat putMask(Mat src, Point center, Size face_size) {

    Log.d(TAG, "src at the START of putMask(): " + src.toString());
    Mat mask_resized = new Mat();
    Mat src_roi = new Mat();
    Mat roi_gray = new Mat();

    resize(mask, mask_resized, face_size);

    Rect roi = new Rect((int) (center.x - face_size.width / 2), (int) (center.y - face_size.height / 2), (int) face_size.width, (int) face_size.height);

    src.submat(roi).copyTo(src_roi);

    Log.d(TAG, "MASK SRC1 :" + src_roi.size());

    Mat mask_grey = new Mat(); 
    Mat roi_rgb = new Mat();
    cvtColor(mask_resized, mask_grey, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    threshold(mask_grey, mask_grey, 230, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    ArrayList<Mat> maskChannels = new ArrayList<>(3);
    ArrayList<Mat> result_mask = new ArrayList<>(3);
    result_mask.add(new Mat());
    result_mask.add(new Mat());
    result_mask.add(new Mat());

    split(mask_resized, maskChannels);

    bitwise_and(maskChannels.get(0), mask_grey, result_mask.get(0));
    bitwise_and(maskChannels.get(1), mask_grey, result_mask.get(1));
    bitwise_and(maskChannels.get(2), mask_grey, result_mask.get(2));

    merge(result_mask, roi_gray);

    bitwise_not(mask_grey, mask_grey);

    ArrayList<Mat> srcChannels = new ArrayList<>(3);
    split(src_roi, srcChannels);
    bitwise_and(srcChannels.get(0), mask_grey, result_mask.get(0));
    bitwise_and(srcChannels.get(1), mask_grey, result_mask.get(1));
    bitwise_and(srcChannels.get(2), mask_grey, result_mask.get(2));

    merge(result_mask, roi_rgb);

    addWeighted(roi_gray, 1, roi_rgb, 1, 0, roi_rgb);

    src = new Mat(src, roi);
    roi_rgb.copyTo(src);

    Log.i(TAG, "src at the END of putMask(): " + src.toString());
    return src;
}
```

}

Версии:
OpenCV 3.4.3
NDK 14b

При простом обнаружении лица, без маски, а просто с обводкой квадратиком, работает хорошо.